# Play Store shows open button instead of continue using dynamic link

Tags: android, firebase, google-play, firebase-dynamic-links

I implemented firebase dynamic links into my app. It should work in this way: 
user click link, it opens play store, 
user click install, 
after installation play store should show `continue` green button, it opens app in determined by link activity that handle firebase dynamic link data

There is one case where play store do not present 'continue' button. If user never had my app on his phone and never had it on his google account. I am able to reproduce that by removing app from phone, removing google account from phone, clearing google and play store data/cache, creating and adding new google account.

In this case user instead of `continue` will get `open` button, that opens app normally and it miss my dynamic link flow.

What Happen: 
[image]

What Should Happen:
[image]

Is this a play store issue or is this Firebase dynamic link configuration issue? If this is play store issue where I can ask about that or fill out a bug report to Google?

Comment: Hmm, the dynamic link flow should happen regardless of the continue link. Does your dynamic links implementation require going to a certain activity - if you check for a link on your default activity, you should be able to receive it

Comment: @IanBarber It should if you implement listener in main activity, that is not a case here, I want Play Store to let user open my app with dynamic link flow, not to workaround a bug, if this is the case.

Comment: I wouldn't say its a workaround - if the user installs but doesn't hit the play store button, and launches the app from the launcher, you'll be in the same situation.

Comment: That is not a question here, I am awared of this case, I want dynamic links to work properly in Play Store

Comment: That's fair! I think this behavior is a bug, but be aware even with a fix it will be a long time before all users are on the latest play store.  You can report Firebase bugs at https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/

Comment: Any news about the bug?

Comment: @IgorRonner Nothing new, if you have similar problem probably submitting that with form provided above will help as they will get more 'points' on that issue.

Comment: @TomaszKryński any solution about this issue?

Comment: @AITAALI_ABDERRAHMANE I am sorry, but answer is still same. Please fill a bug report to increase visibility/increase priority.

Comment: This is so sad to see that even after years of this being raised absolutely no work has been done on this and every year many people get affected by this issue. I mean there has to be some update here.

Comment: Hi, Im still getting uninstall button instead of expected continue after installing app from firebase deep link ! any fix please. Thank you in advance